# Add native service to aosp

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to add a native service written in C++ to the AOSP build.
The first thing I did was to create a native service and client to the AOSP build.
This worked as expected. I could start the service within an adb shell and call it via binder on a adb shell.

The trouble started when I wanted to start my service with init.
I added a **.rc** file to my build

```
service myp /system/bin/myp_service
    class main
```

This did the the trick so that init tried to start it but it failed because of SELinux policies.

So I added a `file_contexts` to my device tree and added:

```
/system/bin/myp_service     u:object_r:myp_exec:s0
```

Next I added a **myp.te** file and added:

```
type myp, domain;
type myp_exec, exec_type, file_type;
type myp_service, service_manager_type;

init_daemon_domain(myp)
net_domain(myp)

binder_use(myp)
binder_service(myp)
add_service(myp, myp_service)
binder_call(myp, binderservicedomain)
binder_call(myp, appdomain)

allow myp myp_service:service_manager add;
```

And finally I added a `service_contexts` file with:

```
myp     u:object_r:myp_service:s0
```

This finally made my service successfully start at boot time.
Unfortunalty I cannot use binder against this service. When I try to connect to the service with my client the call

```
defaultServiceManager()->getService(String16("Demo"))
```

returns a null pointer.

I cannot find any hints in the `dmesg`. 
So I assume I am still missing something for the SElinux but I have no clue what I am missing.
If I shutdown the SELinux with `setenforce` and restart the service then it works fine.
Can anyone give me a hint what I am missing for SELinux or where I can get more information about which policy blocked something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could see the denials like this:

1. `adb logcat | grep "SELinux : avc" > /tmp/logs`
2. Get *sepolicy* current file. (Can be taken from device this way `adb pull sepolicy`.
3. Using `audit2allow` (located in AOSP source code: *external/selinux/prebuilts/bin/audit2allow* or in SDK tools. Do this: `cat /tmp/logs | .external/selinux/prebuilts/bin/audit2allow -p sepolicy`

The *audit2allow* tool will tell you what permission you are missing for the logcat extracted and the current *sepolicy* file, watch-out because you could need to do this several times since fixing some permissions will show the next ones required.

If you have a *userdebug* kind of build you could get `setenforce 0`, logcat with it and all the denials will be in logcat even if you will be permited to do the operation desired. This will leave the *audit2allow* iterations required in 1.

Comment: That did the trick and it told me that I need to add `allow myp default_android_service:service_manager add`.
But unfortunately this is prohibited by a neverallow rule in `domain.te`. Guess I need to dig deeper in the policy files.

Comment: Oops, sorry to hear that, it indeed seems to require deeper digging.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who came across this problem, please make sure your `service_contexts` file is successfully merged with stock `service_contexts` file. If you're building your service for Android O or later, please put this file inside a folder and refer to it in your Makefile by `BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR`[1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r30/Android.mk#1266). And you don't need to add `allow myp default_android_service:service_manager add` if the build system does pick up your `service_contexts`.

Also, about the `domain.te` violation problem, you probably want to attach one of the `coredomain` or `appdomain` attribute to your domain [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r30/public/domain.te#998) with `typeattribute <your_domain> <attribute>;`.

Finally, please double check the following built files to make sure you don't leave any sepolicy configurations out in the final build:

1. $(AOSP_ROOT)/out/target/product//obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.*
2. $(AOSP_ROOT)/out/target/product/potter/obj/ETC/plat_service_contexts_intermediates/service_contexts.*
3. $(AOSP_ROOT)/out/target/product/potter/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/policy.conf